# Links redirect to homepage

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, hyperlink

It's my first time working with a bootstrapped template and all of my links are redirecting back to home? Originally these links pointed to div sections rather than web links:

```
</head>
<body >
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top scrollclass" >
<div class="container">
<div class="navbar-header">
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
</button>
<a class="navbar-brand" href="www.mysite.org">MY SITE</a>
</div>
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#home">HOME</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">ABOUT</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.externallink.com">LINK1</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.externallink.com">LINK2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">CONTACT</a></li>
            <li><a href="#social-section">SOCIAL</a></li>

        </ul>
    </div>
```

This section was always supposed to direct to an outside link, but then didn't work when i put the link in:

```
    <div class="container" id="home">
    <div class="row text-center scrollclass">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <span class="head-main">My Company </span>
            <h3 class="head-last">MY SLOGAN</h3>
            <a href="www.gavinacademy.org/chamilo" class="btn btn-primary   btn-lg ">USELESS BUTTON</a> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The "Useless Button" also redirects to home. Sorry if this seems like a stupid question, guys, but in my defense we had a down site (host's mistake) for 8 weeks and I've been working around the clock playing catch-up on this project. I'm hoping it's just some small syntactical error that I"m missing and fresh eyes will help me to see it. Thanks everyone!

Comment: Not related, but why do you have a massive gap between `data-` and `target`? It should be `data-target`.

Comment: Maybe unrelated, but that first block ends with `</dv>` instead of `</div>`

Comment: It is useful if you can provide a link to your work or use jsfiddle.

Comment: You need to use `http://` or `https://` on your links that are outside your application. `http://www.gavinacademy.org/chamilo` , not simply `www.gavinacademy.org/chamilo`.

Comment: Thanks for responding. Nothing happened when I added http:// (it still links back to the homepage for some reason). Lee the gap was created when I cut and pasted the code, and isn't present in the original code.

Comment: What is your development environment because the code you've posted does not replicate the issue. I would look at your setup.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that the link wasn't working because chamilo (the course management system) had issues. I've fixed the problems and will be submitting fixes to the chamilo git. It's a complex program trying to do too many things at once, and the elements weren't interacting well, resulting in the whole thing going down at random. My links are working now that I've tweaked my chamilo.